# Fancygrid date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with using [Fancygrid.js](https://fancygrid.com) and a date picker? Their docs aren't bad, but I'm not seeing any examples that would help me pass params like last 30 days or last month, etc.

I currently have this as my code:

```
new FancyGrid({
            title: 'Report',
            renderTo: 'newTable',
            data: data,
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            // width: 'fit',
            // height: 'fit',
            paging: true,
            trackOver: true,
            selModel: 'row',
            paging: {
                pageSize: 10,
                pageSizeData: [5,10,20,50],
                refreshButton: true
              },
            tbar: [{
                type: 'search',
                width: 350,
                emptyText: 'Search',
                paramsMenu: true,
                paramsText: 'Parameters'
              }],
            defaults: {
              type: 'string',
              sortable: true
            },
            columns: 
            [
                {
                    index: 'theDate',
                    title: 'Date',
                    type: 'date',
                    width: 150,
                    resizable: true,
                    filter: {
                      header: true
                    },
                    // menu: [{
                    //     text: 'Clear Filter',
                    //     handler: function(menu){
                    //         var grid = FancyGrid.get('newTable');
                    //       grid.clearFilter('theDate');
                    //       menu.hide();
                    //     }
                    //   },'-',{
                    //     text: 'Less than 30',
                    //     handler: function(menu){
                    //       var grid = FancyGrid.get('newTable');
                    //       grid.clearFilter('theDate');
                    //       grid.addFilter('theDate', 30, '<');
                    //       menu.hide();
                    //     }
                    //   },{      
                    //     text: 'More than 35',
                    //     handler: function(menu){
                    //       var grid = FancyGrid.get('newTable');
                    //       grid.clearFilter();
                    //       grid.addFilter('theDate', 35, '>');
                    //       menu.hide();
                    //     }
                    // }],
                }, {
                    index: 'MessagesSent',
                    title: 'Messages',
                    width: 80,
                    resizable: true
                }, {
                    index: 'Clicks',
                    title: 'Clicks',
                    width: 150,
                    resizable: true,
                    type: 'number',
                }, {
                    index: 'Upload',
                    title: 'Upload',
                    width: 150,
                    resizable: true
                }, {
                    index: 'UploadRate',
                    title: 'Upload Rate',
                    width: 150,
                    resizable: true
                }, {
                    index: 'enter',
                    title: 'Enter',
                    width: 50,
                    resizable: true
                }, {
                    index: 'EnterRate',
                    title: 'Enter Rate',
                    width: 150,
                    resizable: true
                }
            ],

          });
        });
```

I have the menu commented out right now, but I want to show filtering options for the last 30, 60 and 90 days if possible. My JSON is coming through like this:

```
{
              MinTrackingEventID: '14864641',
              MaxTrackingEventID: '14888303',
              theDate: '02-28-2019',
              Clicks: '36.000000000',
              Upload: '2.000000000',
              Enter: '0.000000000',
              UploadRate: '0.05555555555555555555',
              EnterRate: '0.00000000000000000000',
              MessagesSent: '0'
            },
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the date that you want to compare against and pass this in into the `addFilter()` statement:

```
   menu: [{
       text: 'Clear Filter',
       handler: function(menu){
         grid.clearFilter('theDate');
         menu.hide();
       }
     },'-',{
       text: 'Less than 30',
       handler: function(menu){
         grid.clearFilter('theDate');
         var date = new Date();
         date.setDate(date.getDate() -30);             
         grid.addFilter('theDate', date, '>');
         menu.hide();
       }
     },{      
       text: 'More than 35',
       handler: function(menu){
         grid.clearFilter('theDate');
         var date = new Date();
         date.setDate(date.getDate() -35);      
         grid.addFilter('theDate', date, '<');
         menu.hide();
       }
   }],
   ...
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/83zadhur/30/) of the above code.

I also removed the repeated calls inside the menu ...

```
var grid = FancyGrid.get('newTable');
```

and instead assigned the return value of the grid initialisation to a variable:

```
  var grid = new FancyGrid({
      ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This work just as I needed. I was going to start converting the JS date stamps and going down that route. But this just works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lz430 great to hear it worked! Good luck with your project and also thanks for pointing me to FancyGrid, it looks really neat!